# How to serialize/deserialize the following object?

Tags: json, jackson

I have a java object as given below. How to serialize/deserialize with Jackson json?

```
public class Employee {

     private String name;
     List<Employee> friends;
}
```

**The JSON:**

```
{"friends":[{"name":"abc"}],[{{"name":"pqr"}}]}
```

**My Implementation class:**

```
public class EmployeeImpl implements Employee, Serializable { 

    private String name;
    private List<Employee> friends;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public List<Employee> getFriends() { return friends; }

    public void setFriends(List<Employee> friends) { this.friends = friends; } 
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String json = "{\"name\":\"gangi\", \"friends\":[{\"name\":\"abc\"},{\"name\":\"pqr\"}]}";
        Employee employee = deserializeJson(json, new TypeReference<EmployeeImpl>(){});
    }

    public static <T> T deserializeJson(String jsonData, TypeReference<T> typeRef) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.<T>readValue(jsonData, typeRef);
    }
}
```

**Exception stacktrace...**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Can not construct instance of Employee, 
problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information at 
[Source: java.io.StringReader@68da4b71; line: 1, column: 29] 
(through reference chain: EmployeeImpl["friends"]) at 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163‌​)
```

Comment: Please format code and do some research. Google is your friend.

Comment: If json isn't really your strong suit, I'd recommend building your objects, serializing them and inspecting the json. That way you know what you should provide for deserialization. Also you might want to show what you've attempted, that didn't work. Showing effort is good, and it allows people to explain what you're doing wrong.

Comment: A question, why do you have a base class Employee? You are not utilizing the declarations of base class also, you are redeclaring the same same fields in the sub-class.

Answer (score 3):

Add following annotation to your Employee interface

```
`@JsonDeserialize(as=EmployeeImpl.class)`
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That works, but the problem is that referencing implementation class name in the interface makes me worry... In fact my interface would live outside of my project.
Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is incorrect. See [http://www.json.org/] on how to define array/lists in json. Example for json building [http://java.dzone.com/tips/json-processing-using-jackson]

Comment: String json = "{\"name\":\"gangi\", \"friends\":[{\"name\":\"abc\"},{\"name\":\"pqr\"}]}";

Comment: I would like to know the approach basically?

Comment: My Implementation class:

public class EmployeeImpl implements Employee, Serializable {

    
    private String name;

    private List<Employee> friends;

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

   
    public List<Employee> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    
    public void setFriends(List<Employee> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

}

Comment: Test Class:

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
        String json = "{\"name\":\"gangi\", \"friends\":[{\"name\":\"abc\"},{\"name\":\"pqr\"}]}";
        Employee employee = deserializeJson(json, new TypeReference<EmployeeImpl>(){});
    }


    public static <T> T deserializeJson(String jsonData, TypeReference<T> typeRef) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.<T>readValue(jsonData, typeRef);
    }

}

Comment: Exception stacktrace....

Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of Employee, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@68da4b71; line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: EmployeeImpl["friends"])
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)

Comment: In your EmployeeImpl POJO, change List<Employee> to List <EmployeeImpl>.

Comment: If you want to use abstract classes see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489532/jackson-json-library-how-to-instantiate-a-class-that-contains-abstract-fields)