# Cannot construct instance of - Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson and I'm having problems, when I try to deserialize an Object I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
    Can not construct instance of net.MyAbstractClass, 
    problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, 
        have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

I am having problems in the attribute:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "@id")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyAbstractClass.class, name = "MyAbstractClass") })
@ManyToOne
private MyAbstractClass object;
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Another discussion on a similar case is done at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32777371/873282. Especially interesting is the comment stating to use `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")`. In that way, the JSON is a bit larger, but it is explicit, which type should be used.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class, Jackson neither.
You should give Jackson information on how to instantiate MyAbstractClass with a concrete type.

See this answer on stackoverflow: [Jackson JSON library: how to instantiate a class that contains abstract fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489532/jackson-json-library-how-to-instantiate-a-class-that-contains-abstract-fields)

And maybe also see [Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Comment: Thanks for help, I resolved with:

`JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "class")`

the `property = "class"`, is coming in my JSON informing what child class will be used.

Comment: Beware, allowing users to specify which class to use during deserialization might lead to vulnerabilities such as [this](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2015/11/09/java_serialization_bug/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference: @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class") does the trick. Like the JPA table descriminator value. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

I was having this issue using lombok's `@Data` and `@Builder` annotations alone, which I replaced with:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
```

And it solved my problem.

Comment: I'm using JUnit5 and this answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 20):

You need to use a concrete class and not an Abstract class while deserializing.
if the Abstract class has several implementations then, in that case, you can use it as below-

```
  @JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({ 
      @Type(value = Bike.class, name = "bike"), 
      @Type(value = Auto.class, name = "auto"), 
      @Type(value = Car.class, name = "car")
    })
    public abstract class Vehicle {
        // fields, constructors, getters, setters
    }
```

Comment: Worked for me here. Important to mention that `Vehicle` has a field `type`, which will create the correct object depending on the `name` defined of it.

Comment: Does this work with resteasy? To me - not!

Answer (score 6):

Your `@JsonSubTypes` declaration does not make sense: it needs to list implementation (sub-) classes, NOT the class itself (which would be pointless). So you need to modify that entry to list sub-class(es) there are; or use some other mechanism to register sub-classes (`SimpleModule` has something like `addAbstractTypeMapping`).

Answer (score 5):

For me there was no default constructor defined for the POJOs I was trying to use. creating default constructor fixed it.

```
public class TeamCode {

    @Expose
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    **public TeamCode() {
    }**

    public TeamCode(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TeamCode{" +
                "value='" + value + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe add an example for that could help people in the future 

Answer (score 5):

In your concrete example the problem is that you don't use this construct correctly:

```
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyAbstractClass.class, name = "MyAbstractClass") })
```

`@JsonSubTypes.Type` should contain the actual non-abstract subtypes of your abstract class.

Therefore if you have:

`abstract class Parent` and the concrete subclasses

`Ch1 extends Parent` and
`Ch2 extends Parent`

Then your annotation should look like:

```
@JsonSubTypes({ 
          @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Ch1.class, name = "ch1"),
          @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Ch2.class, name = "ch2")
})
```

Here `name` should match the value of your 'discriminator':

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, 
property = "type")
```

in the `property` field, here it is equal to `type`. So `type` will be the key and the value you set in `name` will be the value.

Therefore, when the json string comes if it has this form:

```
{
 "type": "ch1",
 "other":"fields"
}
```

Jackson will automatically convert this to a `Ch1` class.

If you send this:

```
{
 "type": "ch2",
 "other":"fields"
}
```

You would get a `Ch2` instance.

Comment: Nice explanation. Had to put ```include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,``` to make it work for me.

Comment: Does this work with resteasy? To me - not!

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs= ConcreteCLass.class)`

Answer (score 1):

Setting a default constructor helped to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Use lombok annotation.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "id"})
public class CreationUser {
    @Builder.Default
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name = "";

    @Builder.Default
    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lombok I had the same issue, I have tried this to solve

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
```