# jackson throw JsonMappingException can not construct instance of

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

//interface

```
public interface NotificationPayload {
}
```

//Classes implement interface

```
public ClassA implements NotificationPayload {...}
public ClassB implements NotificationPayload {...}
...
public ClassX implements NotificationPayload {...}
```

//Message to send

```
public class Notification<T extends NotificationPayload> {
    private T data; //T may be ClassA/ClassB/ClassC.../ClassX
    ...
}
```

When I receive a message as a json, I want to convert it to Notification again by using ObjectMapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)

json example:

```
{
    "type":"ClassA",
    "userId":10087
}
```

I convert it:

```
Notification notif = objectMapper.readValue(json, Notification.class);
```

it throw exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of 
com.common.kafka.notification.NotificationPayload: abstract types
either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
contain additional type information
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
com.common.kafka.notification.Notification["data"])
```

I had read from this question: [Cannot construct instance of - Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750681/cannot-construct-instance-of-jackson#) but seem like It cannot help because I have too many Class implement from interface, not only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jackson's annotation to achieve polymorphic deserialization.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ClassA.class, name = "ClassA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ClassB.class, name = "ClassB")
})
public interface NotificationPayload {
}

public class ClassA implements NotificationPayload {

    private Integer userId;

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}

public class Notification <T extends NotificationPayload> {

    private T data; //T may be ClassA/ClassB/ClassC.../ClassX

    @JsonCreator
    public Notification(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonStr = "{\"type\":\"ClassB\",\"userId\":10087}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Notification notification = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Notification.class);
    }
}
```

All the annotations you can find [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations)

Comment: works flawlessly!