# Java, Jackson: Deep Copy Interface

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson to deep-copy an object, like so:

```
   Map<String,Object> props = mapper.convertValue(prototype, Map.class); 
   Command command = mapper.convertValue(props, Command.class);
```

However, since `Command` is an interface without `@JsonTypeInfo` attached, this copy fails with error: `Can not construct instance of Command.. abstract type`.

I don't want to annotate the interface.  I want to provide type information at the conversation level.

How do I do that?

---

I thought this would work:

```
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

Whereby type info would automatically be added for both de/serialization, but I get:

```
Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.Map
```

So the Map is not getting the type info it needs.

Comment: @RobertMoskal - This isn't about excluding fields, its about providing the type information programmatically for `convertValue()`.

Comment: Sorry about that. Seems like the filter technique should work no?

Comment: @RobertMoskal No worries... I'm not familiar with the filter technique.

Comment: It's a duplicate of the reverse problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489532/jackson-json-library-how-to-instantiate-a-class-that-contains-abstract-fields

Comment: @RobertMoskal Those solutions all require TypeInfo be set on the interface or classes... I'm wanting to do it programmatically at the conversion.

Comment: @mtyson you can set TypeInfo in a mixin for Command class for the given object mapper: objectMapper.addMix(...).convertValue(...)